# How can I make wget rename downloaded files to not include the query string?

Tags: http, rename, wget, podcasts

I'm downloading a site with wget and a lot of the links have queries attached to them, so when I do this:

```
wget -nv -c -r -H -A mp3 -nd http://url.to.old.podcasts.com/
```

I end up with a lot of files like this:

```
1.mp3?foo=bar
2.mp3?blatz=pow
3.mp3?fizz=buzz
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
1.mp3
2.mp3
3.mp3
```

This is all taking place in ubuntu linux and I've got wget 1.10.2.

I know I can do this after I get everything via a script to rename everything. However I'd really like a solution from within wget so I can see the correct names as the download is happening.

Can anyone help me unravel this?

Comment: Post your question at www.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @TutorialPoint why?  question is looking for a within-wget-way-to-do-it, SO would just migrate it back here.

Comment: Well, there is no within-wget-way-to-do-it

Comment: @ayrnieu: not in one command, no.  and not without a helper.  but you can certainly do it with as few as n+1 `wget` commands (if not fewer).

Answer (score 31):

If the server is kind, it might be sticking a Content-Disposition header on the download advising your client of the correct filename. Telling wget to listen to that header for the final filename is as simple as:

```
wget --content-disposition
```

You'll need a newish version of wget to use this feature.

I have no idea how well it handles a server claiming a filename of '/etc/passwd'.

Comment: I have no problem with this answer, as it no doubt works for some situations.  Unfortunately, it didn't work for me with respect to some [cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)-served pages with `?v=blah` type versioning in them.  There may be some cloudfront-specific way to request a document without these, I don't know, but I failed to find one, so something like one of the other answers may well be necessary in such a case.  (If anyone knows of a way to strip - or get Cloudfront not to serve - the `v=` strings, I'd love to hear about it.)

Comment: Manual says:
```If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can currently result in
extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD" request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by
default. This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use "Content-Disposition" headers to describe what the name of a downloaded
file should be.``` I don't think it's 100% reliable solution.

Answer (score 21):

I realized after processing a large batch that I should have instructed `wget` to ignore the query strings.  I did not want to do it over again so I made this script which worked for me:

```
# /bin/bash
for i in `find $1 -type f`
do
    mv $i `echo $i | cut -d? -f1`
done
```

Put that in a file like `rmqstr` and `chmod +x rmqstr`
Syntax: `./rmqstr <directory (defaults to .)>`

It will remove the query strings from all filenames recursively.

Comment: I would add ` -name "*\?*"` to find part to limit only to needed files :)

Comment: minimalism in it's beauty :)

Comment: This doesn't take paths with spaces into account

Comment: `I should have instructed wget to ignore the query strings` How do this?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: easiest way is to pre-process the URLs to remove the query string before passing it to `wget`

Answer (score 5):

I think, in order to get `wget` to save as a filename different than the URL specifies, you need to use the `-O filename` argument.  That only does what you want when you give it a single URL -- with multiple URLs, all downloaded content ends up in `filename`.

But that's really the answer.  Instead of trying to do it all in one `wget` command, use multiple commands.  Now your workflow becomes:

1. Run `wget` to get the base HTML file(s) containing your links;
2. Parse for URLs;
3. Foreach URL ending in `mp3`,

   1. process URL to get a filename (eg turn `http://foo/bar/baz.mp3?gargle=blaster` into `baz.mp3`
   2. (optional) check that filename doesn't exist
   3. run `wget <URL> -O <filename>`

That solves your problem, but now you need to figure out how to grab the base files to find your `mp3` URLs.

Do you have a particular site/base URL in mind?  Steps 1 and 3 will be easier to handle with a concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

Look at these two commands I created to clone a site, and after clone is done, you can execute second command.

The second command will take a look in entire clone, search for "*?*" file pattern names, and will remove query string from the file name.

```
# Clone entire site.
    wget --content-disposition --execute robots=off --recursive --no-parent --continue --no-clobber http://example.com

# Remove query string from a static resource.
for i in `find $1 -type f -name "*\?*"`; do mv $i `echo $i | cut -d? -f1`; done
```

(See it in [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/vpadhariya/90ab71c2a6a1203f5f9aa75ad5c5f32a).)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as It does exactly what is required.

Answer (score 3):

In order to properly rename the files you have to account for spaces in file name, which is a possibility and will mess the for loop.

Here is an improved version :

```bash
find . -type f -name "*\?*" -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; 
do 
    mv -f "$file" "`echo $file | cut -d? -f1`"; 
done
```

This ensures that files with spaces are properly handled by the loop (using \0 as delimiter) and by the mv command (double quotes)

There were only a couple complex cases where it did not work but otherwise this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

> so I can see the correct names as the download is happening.

OK.  Use wget as you normally do; use the post-wget script that you normally use, but process wget's output so that it's easier on the eyes:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec wget --progress=bar:force $* 2>&1 | \
  perl -pe 'BEGIN { $| = 1 } s,(?<=`)([^\x27?]+),\e[36;1m$1\e[0m, if /^Saving/'
cgi-cut # rename files
```

This will still show the `?foo=bar` as you download, but will display the rest of the name in bright cyan.

Comment: This somewhat solves the issue of the filenames being displayed, but the OP also wants the final file name not to have the query string.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar approach as @Gregory Wolf because his code always created error messages like this:

> mv: './file' and './file' are the same file

Thus I first check if there is a query string in the filename before moving the file:

```
for f in $(find $1 -type f); do
    if [ $f = ${f%%\?*} ]; then continue; fi
    mv "${f}" "${f%%\?*}"
done
```

This will recursively check every file and remove all query strings in their filenames if available.

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't intended to be a method to rename files after downloading - that's been answered.  Instead I want to suggest what to do when you realise the files downloaded with a query string are mere duplicates that you want to exclude.  This can happen in for example a WordPress site where paths normally don't include a query string.  All you need to do here is not attempt to download any link including a '?', eg:

```
wget -km --reject-regex '.*\?.*' https://tomlehrersongs.com/
```

Answer (score -2):

Even easier is this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196253/how-do-you-rename-files-specifically-in-a-list-that-wget-will-use

This suggests a method that essentially uses wget's rename function (can be altered to include directory) for multiple files.  See the second version proposed.

Comment: Can you please quote the relevant information from the link, so we know which material, you believe answers this question.