# Downloading multiple files, and specifying output filenames with wget

Tags: wget

I'm using `wget` with the `-i` option to download a list of files from a URL.

However, I want to specify the names that these files will be saved with as well.

I see you can do that with a single file using `-O`, and can specify a directory with `-P`; is it possible to download a list of files, and specify filenames for each of them?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/61025/how-can-i-make-wget-rename-downloaded-files-to-not-include-the-query-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### wget

Probably not with wget

### perl

Something like ...

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -lane 'getstore($F[0],$F[1])' urls_and_filenames.txt
```

For Windows use " instead of '

### curl

I note that [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) has some options that might be relevant

> -K, --config
>
> Specify which config file to read curl arguments from.

…

> --url
>
> Specify a URL to fetch. This option is mostly handy when you want to specify URL(s) in a config file.
>
> This option may be used any number of times. To control where this URL is written, use the -o, --output or the -O, --remote-name options.

…

> `-o, --output <file>`
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the  specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
>
> `curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"`
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> `curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"`
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.

…

Answer (score 1):

Not `wget`, but `aria2c` supports this https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#input-file

```
aria2c -i fileList.txt
```

For example, the content of fileList.txt is:

```
http://server/file.iso http://mirror/file.iso
  dir=/iso_images
  out=file.img
http://foo/bar
```

If aria2 is executed with `-i fileList.txt -d /tmp` options, then `file.iso` is saved as `/iso_images/file.img` and it is downloaded from `http://server/file.iso` and `http://mirror/file.iso`. The file `bar` is downloaded from `http://foo/bar` and saved as `/tmp/bar`.

Comment: +1 for aria2c.  It's a powerful tool and has other nice features like parallel downloading as well.