# Downloading multiple files with wget and handling parameters

Tags: linux, shell-script, wget, centos-6

How can I download multiple files using wget? I also want to rename the files. Here are the commands I'm running one by one (copy/paste on terminal):

```
    wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.filesonic.com/file/812720774/PS11.rar -O part11.rar
    wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.filesonic.com/file/812721094/PS12.rar -O part12.rar
    wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.filesonic.com/file/812720804/PS13.rar -O part13.rar
    wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.filesonic.com/file/812720854/PS14.rar -O part14.rar
........ and so on..
```

What can I do to download all these files one by one?

Comment: This is very similar to http://superuser.com/questions/336669/downloading-multiple-files-and-specifying-output-filenames-with-wget

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a short shell script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line
do
  wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt $line -O ${line##*/}
done < filelist
```

Where `filelist` is a text file that contains each download link, one by one. `${line##*/}` will extract the filename itself and therefore produce something similar to the following commands:

```
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://download/file1.rar -O file1.rar
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://download/file2.rar -O file2.rar
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt http://download/file3.rar -O file3.rar
```

If you want to run these in parallel, you can also just wrap the `wget` line inside parentheses to run it in a subshell.

```
(wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt $line -O ${line##*/})
```

Or add an ampersand. This would however mean that the downloads will still run when you cancel the script. You'd have to kill them manually for each process.

```
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt $line -O ${line##*/} &
```