# How to Download Multiple XML files from different URLs

Tags: shell, wget

@slhck provided a useful answer to this similar question.

[Downloading multiple files with wget and handling parameters](https://superuser.com/q/374053/121336)

This code was provided to read urls from a text file **filelist**, then run a loop to download each.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash 
    while read line 
      do   
        wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt $line -O ${line##*/} 
    done < filelist
```

As I'm not familiar with shell scripts, I am wondering if you could download multiple xml files by:

- creating a simple comma seperated text file **filelist**
- read from:

**filelist**

renamedfile.xml, url-01.php 
renamedFileDifferent.xml, url-02.php 
specificFileRename.xml, "url-03"
newFilename.xml, "url-04"

- read through each line
- split the line into newfile, remoteFile
- And run:

  ```
  wget -O newfile remoteFile >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

**Is it possible to write this in a shell script? Can you provide an example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text from before the comma you use `${line/,*}`.

(What this actually does is replace ",*" or *all the text from the comma onwards* with *empty string* - leaving only the part of the string before the comma)

To get the text from after the comma you use `${line/*,}`.

So the full command would be:

```
while read line
  do
    wget -O ${line/,*} ${line/*,} >/dev/null 2>&1 
done < filelist
```

or, on one line:

```
while read line; do echo wget -O ${line/,*} ${line/*,} >/dev/null 2>&1; done < filelist
```

In Windows (assuming you've installed wget, from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm, and set your path correctly), it would be:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1*" %a in (filelist) do wget -O %a %b
```

Comment: What directory is a good place to put the text file, and shell file typically? This will be run as a cron job.

Comment: Wherever you want to run it from (and save the files to). eg. if you put `filelist` and `test.sh` in sub directory of your home, and then run it from there, that's where it will save the files.

Comment: I'm not sure it will run as expected if run as a cron job. You will want to specify absolute paths in the filelist (`~\downloaddir\renamedfile.xml`) and probably in the crontab as well (`46 8 * * cd ~\downloaddir; test.sh` or maybe just `46 8 * * ~\downloaddir\test.sh`). Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204/why-doesnt-my-cron-job-work-properly and http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/129329-crontab-working-directory.html

Comment: another option is to harcode the paths into the script, eg.

`wget -O ~/downloaddir/${line/,*} ${line/*,} >/dev/null 2>&1` and  

`done < ~/downloaddir/filelist`