# How to make wget resolve HTTP queries?

Tags: linux, wget

Consider the download link

```
http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/latest/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4?old_path=/&filename=accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4&format=zip
```

with the query part

```
?old_path=/&filename=accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4&format=zip
```

Downloading the file in `firefox` 37.0 causes the query to be resolved and a download of a `.zip` file while

```
wget 'http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/latest/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4?old_path=/&filename=accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4&format=zip'
```

retrieves a file named `acct_mgr-0.4.4?old_path=%2F&filename=accountmanagerplugin%2Ftags%2Facct_mgr-0.4.4&format=zip` which one definitely should rename in order to work with it on the command line.

How to get `wget` to store the download as `.zip` with the correct name without the need to figure out this name (`diff-from-_-14559-to-accountmanagerplugin_tags_acct_mgr-0.4.4-14559.zip` in the example) and specify it to the `-O/--output-document=` option?

I checked [How can I make wget rename downloaded files to not include the query string?](https://superuser.com/questions/61025/how-can-i-make-wget-rename-downloaded-files-to-not-include-the-query-string), but adding `--content-disposition` doesn't help.

Comment: check http://superuser.com/questions/61025/how-can-i-make-wget-rename-downloaded-files-to-not-include-the-query-string?rq=1

Comment: --content-disposition doesn't help because it's not recognized by wget?

Comment: @golimar I can only assume that it is recognized. How to check except that the download still has the same name instead of `.zip`? As far as I understood it only works when there's a disposition HTTP header in the response.

Comment: Check about that parameter in the wget manpage; also try --server-response to confirm that the server is using that header